# SharePoint and OpenID Connect

Tags: sharepoint-server, saml, openid-connect-protocol

We are today using SharePoint Server and have a newly implemented OpenID Connect (OIDC) provider (certified) which we would like to use to authenticate/authorize users with.

Is it possible to use OIDC with SharePoint?
If not, is it possible to use SAML 2.0?

We also have MS Web Application Proxy in front

Answer (score 0):

No and no. SharePoint Server only supports SAML 1.1 and I strongly recommend not using it due to configuration overhead and poor user experience.

Since you have WAP + AD FS, if you domain-join your WAP boxes you can create a non-claims aware relying party in AD FS that leverages Kerberos Constrained Delegation to provide access to Windows authenticated (Kerberos-enabled) applications.

If you have Azure AD P1 licensing, you could also implement the Azure App Proxy which is an agent that runs on one or more servers on-prem (recommended to dedicate them). Advantage here is that you don't have to open ports in your firewall(s) to any internal web application and you can still enable pre-authentication within Azure.

Comment: If SAML 1.1 is not recommended then how to integrate with Azure AD for authentication which returns ID token as JWT? Kindly advise. Thanks in advance.